# Wildcard not being interpreted in if statement

Tags: wildcards, directory-structure, variable-substitution

I am currently writing the below script. The code looks at a certain directory for a filename inputted by the user. The script first checks to see if the input file is a gzip, if so, it runs the corresponding checks. If the file is not gzipped it responds with an incompatible file text.

The issue I am running into is on line `7`. No matter the file extension, I am receiving incompatible file as the final output.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
L0_Report_Generator=("/home/ubuntu/$gzip_file")
echo -n "Enter File Directory:"$gzip_file 
read  $gzip_file
for gzip_file in {$L0_Report_Generator}; do
  if [[ $gzip_file = "test_sub"*"gz" ]] #Check file extension for gzip compression
      then
         gunzip $gzip_file
         echo "file Level 0 QC Check"
         echo ${DATE}
         echo "File Header"
         cat $gzip_file | head
         echo "Total Records"
         cat $gzip_file | wc -l
         echo "File Unique Records Size"
         cat $L0_Report_Generator | sort -u | wc -l
         rm $gzip_file 
    else [[ $gzip_file != "test_sub"*"gz" ]] #If file is anything other than .gz and csv - rort will not run
       then
         echo "incompatible file"
         fi
done
```

Comment: Since when has `[[` required quoting?

Comment: the only times I've seen `[[` require quoting is due to the use of wildcard which is why I used it in this script.

Comment: I'm not being interpreted where??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for a ".gz" filename extension using a wildcard expression inside of an if-statement then you would use an expression such as the following:

```bsh
if [[ "${gzip_file}" = *.gz ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

Here is how you might test it out:

```bsh
if [[ "file.gz" = *.gz ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

and:

```bsh
if [[ "file.txt" = *.gz ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

The first example produces `true` as its output and the second example produces `false`.

Now let's look at your code. Your if-statement has the following conditional expression instead:

```bsh
[[ $gzip_file = "test_sub"*"gz" ]]
```

In particular, you're including "test_sub" as a substring in your match pattern. Try removing that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @igal said about checking the file's extension, You have a lot of errors in variable syntax and usage. Start with line 3:

```
L0_Report_Generator=("/home/ubuntu/$gzip_file")
```

The variable `gzip_file` hasn't been set yet, so `$gzip_file` will be replaced by nothing when the shell expands it. Also, the parentheses in `var=(something)` assigns an array instead of a plain variable, and in this case that doesn't make any sense.

The fourth line, `echo -n "Enter File Directory:"$gzip_file`, has the same problem with the variable `gzip_file`. It also has the problem that `echo -n` is unpredictable and will do different things under different versions of the `echo` command. To print a string without a linefeed, you're much better off using `printf "%s" "string to print"`, but in this case there's a better option that I'll get to in a minute.

The fifth line, `read  $gzip_file`, appears to be intended to read user input into the variable `gzip_file`, but that's not what it does. In the shell, when you put `$` in front of a variable name, that *gets* the current value of the variable. Here, you want to *set* it, so you must leave the `$` off: `read gzip_file`. But that's not what I'd do. I'd include the prompt (which you `echo` on line 4) as part of the `read` command:

```
read -p "Enter File Directory:" gzip_file
```

Ok, now for line 6:

```
for gzip_file in {$L0_Report_Generator}; do
```

This appears to be setting `gzip_file` *again* (replacing the value we just `read` into it). Are you actually trying to set `gzip_file` here, and the previous variable references really should have been a different variable (maybe `gzip_dir` instead)?

Also, the `in` part doesn't make any sense. I think you're trying to use the variable `L0_Report_Generator`, but in that case the open brace should go *after* the dollar sign. But that doesn't entirely make sense either, because `${L0_Report_Generator}` will (if I understand what this is supposed to do) just be the path to a directory. `for ... in` does not iterate over the content of directories, it iterates over a list of *words*, like `for var in word1 word2 "word 3 which has several spaces in it" word4; do`. If you want to get a list of files in a directory, you need to use a wildcard, like `for var in dir/*; do` -- the shell will expand the wildcard-containing file pattern into a list of matching files, each treated as a word, and iterate over them. You also have the option to limit matches to files with a specific extension by including that in the pattern, like `dir/*.gz`.

Three other notes: I recommend against using uppercase variable names like `DATE`, to avoid conflicts with the various all-caps environment variables that have special meaning to the shell or some utilities. Also, always double-quote your variable references (i.e. use `"$var"` instead of just `$var`) to avoid unexpected parsing oddities. And the `else` clause doesn't have a test, so using `else [[ some test ]]` doesn't make sense (and having `then` after `else` is a syntax error).

So if I understood what the script is supposed to do, I'd recommend replacing the beginning of the script with:

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)    # Note lowercase variable
read -p "Enter File Directory:" gzip_dir
L0_Report_Generator="/home/ubuntu/$gzip_dir"

for gzip_file in "${L0_Report_Generator}"/*.gz; do
```

...And then (if the .gz pattern above is what you want), you don't need the `if` to check whether `$gzip_file` has a .gz extension, because the wildcard pattern will only list .gz files.

One more note: [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) is very helpful for pointing out basic errors in shell scripts. It misses a lot of what I pointed out, but caught the stray `then` (which I initially missed).

Comment: This was extremely helpful - addressing the above ultimately allowed for my code to begin functioning properly. A million thanks!